# duplicate results from mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have this select query

```
SELECT * FROM Category cgy, Product pd, Transactions tr 
 WHERE  cgy.cid= 1
   AND tr.payment_status = 'Completed'
   AND pd.pid=cgy.pid`
```

with that query I am only meant to get 1 result back but unfortunately I am getting 2 of the same result. I don't understand why because I have join both the primary key and foreign key.

`Transactions` doesn't have any key related to any of those tables

**UPDATE**

product table

```
pid  Name  

1    green
2    red
3    blue
```

Category Table

```
cid    pid
1       1 
2       2
3       3
```

Transactions table

```
tid     payment_statue    address1
1          Completed        1 hello road
2          incomplete       2 inactive road
```

Comment: Avoid (implicit) comma-join syntax. Use (explicit) JOIN syntax instead. It won't solve the problem, but it will make logical errors easier to spot. And how can transactions be unrelated?

Comment: When you include Transactions in your query you will duplicate the number of rows equal to the number of rows in your Transactions table. This explains why you get twice the rows since there is 2 rows in Transactions.

Comment: @apartridge how can i stop the duplication?  I need to include transaction.

Comment: @EmilyKenpachi You didn't explain how `transactions` related to `product` and/or `category` tables.

Comment: Did Category table having CatID column?

Comment: your query seems correct : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ca9f/4

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan i didn't see any primary key and foreign key in your example. Thats why it works

Answer (score 0):

After your updated question, this query is returning single result if you have one row with value of `payment_status` as '`completed`'. if you have multiple rows as payment_status as '`completed`' then add a `foreign key` reference from `product` table say `pid`.

So you can try :

```
alter table transactions add(pid int(10));
```

AND

```
ALTER TABLE transactions ADD CONSTRAINT fk_product_id FOREIGN KEY (pid) references product(pid);
```

and rewrite the query adding :

```
select * FROM Category cgy, Product pd, Transactions tr WHERE cgy.cid = 1 and tr.payment_status = 'completed' and pd.pid = cgy.pid and pd.pid = tr.pid
```

This will work.

Comment: so i need to add `pid` to transaction table?

Comment: only if transactions is in some way related to products

Comment: yes. it will help, and yes you need a relation between either category or product relation to transaction.